# Add Sheet name to Worksheet Change Log

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Good Afternoon,

I found this code online to create a log of changes and I want to apply it to multiple sheets. How do I make it pull the name of the sheet where the cell was changed?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strAddress As String
Dim val
Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim Rw As Long

If Intersect(Target, Range("A:Z")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   'change range to suit
dtmTime = Now()
With Target
      val = .Value
       strAddress = .Address
End With

Rw = Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets("Log")
    .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress
    .Cells(Rw, 2) = Environ("UserName")
    .Cells(Rw, 3) = dtmTime
    .Cells(Rw, 4) = val

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells(Rw, 5) = me.Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using multiple Worksheet_Change event subs and switch to a single Workbook_Sheetchange in the ThisWorkbook private code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case LCase(Sh.Name)
        Case "sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A:Z")) Is Nothing Then
                On Error GoTo exit_out
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Dim rw As Long, t As Range
                For Each t In Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A:Z"))
                    With Worksheets("Log")
                    rw = Worksheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        .Cells(rw, "A") = t.Address(0, 0)
                        .Cells(rw, "B") = Environ("UserName")
                        .Cells(rw, "C") = Now
                        .Cells(rw, "D") = t.Value
                        .Cells(rw, "E") = Sh.Name
                    End With
                Next t
            End If
        Case "log"
            'do nothing
    End Select

exit_out:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice work!  Great error handling for the Application.EnableEvents.  Too many people fail to handle that correctly and it's good to see someone doing it right.